# WebHdfsException in hue browser

Tags: hadoop, hue

In hue browser I am facing the following issue. I am using Hortonworks 2.1

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    
Django Version: 1.2.3
Exception Type: WebHdfsException
Exception Value:    
<urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
Exception Location: /usr/lib/hue/desktop/libs/hadoop/src/hadoop/fs/webhdfs.py in _stats, line 209
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python2.6
Python Version: 2.6.6
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you enabled WebHdfs [correctly](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/latest/CDH5-Installation-Guide/cdh5ig_cdh_hue_configure.html?scroll=topic_15_4_1_unique_1)? If you have more information you can also contact the [hue-user](http://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/group/hue-user) list.